# How can I do Windows Authentication with WCF over http?

Tags: wcf

Can anyone show me how to do Windows Authentication with WCF over http? At a fundamental level, I don't think https is required for Windows Authentication. The s in https encrypts the traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/8-steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba) is what you are looking for.